# Show a random variable is not uniformly tight

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

How can I show that $X_{n}\sim N(0,n)$ is not uniformly tight? i.e., $X_{n} \neq O_{p}(1)$?

The definition of **uniformly tight** I'm using here is:

> For every $\epsilon$, there is a $M$ st $\sup P(|X_{n}|>M)<\epsilon$.

I'm trying to construct an $\epsilon$ so that $\sup P(|X_{n}|>M)<\epsilon$ for no $M$, but I'm stuck at how to...

Thanks!

Comment: $P(|X_n| >M)=P(|\sqrt n Y| >M)=P(|Y| > M /\sqrt n) \to 1$ where $Y \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Or, write down then probability in terms of the density function and make  a simple change of variable. You have asked many questions of this type without showing any effort on your part.

Comment: Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy for your responses but I never quite understand the hints I get. Why does (||>/√n)→1? also how does that help me find my epsilon?

Comment: I am saying that $(X_n)$ is **not tight**.